# Swift method missing from Framework header when using ErrorType

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm writing a framework in Swift that is intended to be used with other projects. I can use all of my public functions expect for a function that uses an ErrorType parameter in the declaration of the function.

Here's the method decleration:

```
public func doSomething(completionHandler: (getSomething: [elements])->(), errorHanlder: (ErrorType) -> ())
```

This method is missing from the header.

What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorType` is not an `@objc` protocol, so you cannot use it from Objective-C code.  If you want to be compatible with Objective-C, your best bet is to use the `NSError` type instead of `ErrorType`.